# serilog format SourceContext for showing only assembly name

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, serilog

I configured my project to use Serilog for logging using dependecy injection. 
I use the following schema in the classes constructor:

```
namespace FlickPopper.API.Controllers {

    public class ValuesController : Controller {
        private ILogger<ValuesController> _logger;
        public MyClass(ILogger<ValuesController> logger) {
           _logger = logger;
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, serilog creates the logger calling to `Log.ForContext<classname>`

My settings are:

```
  "Serilog": {
      "WriteTo": [
        {
          "Name": "RollingFile",
          "Args": {
            "pathFormat": "Logs\\log-{Date}.txt",
            "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
          }
        }
      ],
      "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ]
    }
```

So, the logs seems like this:

```
2018-01-26 22:20:08 [INF] [FlickPopper.API.Controllers.ValuesController] Get all values
```

It's any way to format the SourceContext property to show only the assembly name in the logs, somthing like this?

```
2018-01-26 22:20:08 [INF] [FlickPopper.API] Get all values
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you use injected `ILogger<T>`, under the hood Serilog logger is created by [SerilogLoggerProvider](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging/Extensions/Logging/SerilogLoggerProvider.cs) that implements `ILoggerProvider` interface. This interface has the only method:

```
public interface ILoggerProvider : IDisposable
{
    ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName);
}
```

The passed `categoryName` is used as value for `{SourceContext}` property in message format. And ASP.NET Core passes it as fully-qualified name (e.g. `FlickPopper.API.Controllers.ValuesController`).

So this string value should be fixed not in Serilog code or configuration, but in ASP.NET Core logging infrastructure.

The responsible class for creation of that value in first place is `Logger<T>` class. Instances of `Logger<T>` are instantiated when you inject `ILogger<T>` into your classes. Here is [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerOfT.cs) of its constructor:

```
public class Logger<T> : ILogger<T>
{
    public Logger(ILoggerFactory factory)
    {
        if (factory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory));
        }

        _logger = factory.CreateLogger(TypeNameHelper.GetTypeDisplayName(typeof(T)));
    }

    //  ...
}
```

That call to `TypeNameHelper.GetTypeDisplayName(typeof(T))` returns fully-qualified name that then is passed to `ILoggerFactory` and eventually to `SerilogLoggerProvider`.

So if you want to change that behavior and adjust the `categoryName` passed to `ILoggerFactory`, you should have your own implementation of `ILogger<T>` that makes required call to `ILoggerFactory.CreateLogger()`. It's not that difficult, because `Logger<T>` class is very thin and is based on `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger` implementation. Here is the class that is a copy of `Logger<T>` except for one line producing logger category name:

```
public class LoggerEx<T> : ILogger<T>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public LoggerEx(ILoggerFactory factory)
    {
        if (factory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory));
        }

        _logger = factory.CreateLogger(typeof(T).Assembly.GetName().Name);
    }

    IDisposable ILogger.BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return _logger.BeginScope(state);
    }

    bool ILogger.IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return _logger.IsEnabled(logLevel);
    }

    void ILogger.Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        _logger.Log(logLevel, eventId, state, exception, formatter);
    }
}
```

You should also replace the standard implementation of `ILogger<T>` with this one in your services registration:

`services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(LoggerEx<>));`

Now the instances of `LoggerEx<T>` will be injected to the controllers and `{SourceContext}` will have a value you built:

> 2018-01-27 09:54:21 [INF] [TestProject.TestApplication] Hello!

Comment: Using Serilog on .net 6 works a bit different the custom logger works but then it doesn't pull the config I have in my appsettings. My problem was I was using Serilog's static logger instead of ILogger<T> in case someone else has that issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, except I wanted to include only the class/interface name.

I solved this by creating a custom enricher.

```
// Create logger
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  // ...
  .Enrich.With(new SourceContextEnricher())
  // ...
  .CreateLogger();

public class SourceContextEnricher : ILogEventEnricher {

  public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory) {
    if (logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue("SourceContext", out var property)) {
      var scalarValue = property as ScalarValue;
      var value = scalarValue?.Value as string;

      if (value?.StartsWith("FlickPopper.API.") ?? false) {
        var lastElement = value.Split(".").LastOrDefault();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastElement)) {
          logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(new LogEventProperty("SourceContext", new ScalarValue(lastElement)));
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```