# Serilog SourceContext class name only via appsettings.json only approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, serilog

I'm using Serilog ASP.NET Core for my Blazor (Server) project, I configure the logger via `appsettings.json` and this is how my output template looks like:

```
"[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u4}] ] [{SourceContext}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
```

I use `builder.Host.UseSerilog()` to add it to the app and `ILogger` to inject it into my components.

What I'd like to have is to display **class name only** instead of showing full assembly+class name like it does with `{SourceContext}`.

Is it possible?

I already tried this one:
[serilog format SourceContext for showing only assembly name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470090/serilog-format-sourcecontext-for-showing-only-assembly-name)

After that the configuration of the logger (`appsettings.json`) didn't work.

That other question has a code based approach, whereas I prefer a configuration only one via `appsettings.json`.

Comment: @DavidG I understand your reasoning about this question being a dupe, but the difference here is in asking for a solution via `appsettings.json` settings. Maybe a title update would fix that. That other question has a code approach answer.

Comment: @pfx The other question doesn't specify a code-based or config-based approach, which is why I thought your answer would work there too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply an expression via an [`ExpressionTemplate`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions#formatting-with-expressiontemplate).

Serilogs GitHub page shows a [recipe](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions#recipes) for only logging the type name and no namespace.

> Trim down `SourceContext` to a type name only:
>
> ```
> Substring(SourceContext, LastIndexOf(SourceContext, '.') + 1)
> ```
>
> This expression takes advantage of `LastIndexOf()` returning -1 when no . character appears in SourceContext, to yield a startIndex of 0 in that case.

---

Your `appsettings.json`  configuration has to specify to use an `ExpressionTemplate`.  For the `Console` logger  that looks like below.

```
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
  },
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "Console",
      "Args": {
        "formatter": {
          "type": "Serilog.Templates.ExpressionTemplate, Serilog.Expressions",
          "template": "{@t:HH:mm:ss} - {@l:u} - {Substring(SourceContext, LastIndexOf(SourceContext, '.') + 1)}: {@m}\n{@x}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that you'll need to include `NuGet` packages  [Serilog.Expressions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Expressions) and [Serilog.Settings.Configuration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Settings.Configuration) starting from version 3.3.0.

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Expressions" Version="3.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.3.0" />
```

Comment: @pfx thank you, that's exactly what I wanted

Comment: @DavidG that's not exactly a duplicate....but ok, btw thanks for closing my previous question without giving me chance to clarify

Comment: @DavidG This answer would not suit there, since the request for the assembly name can't be retrieved from a settings only approach, since `SourceContext` is a namespace+class `string`. Nor is there an alternative to get the assembly from. I tend to believe that it is this what makes this question and answer different.